# How do I view which columns triggered an IntegrityError using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, exception, sqlalchemy

I just spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out why I was getting an `IntegrityError` with a type mismatch, because we thought it was an entirely different column.

I was looking at the different properties of the exception but it didn't appear to be `params` and I didn't notice anything else that seemed promising. If it had said something like `column 'id' is an integer and you're trying to give me 'str', dummy!` then it would have taken us all of ten seconds.

Is there a way to see which columns/values triggered an IntegrityError (or other kinds of error) in SQLAlchemy? The [docs were a little sparse on details](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError).

Comment: So's the DB-API pep on [IntegrityError](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#integrityerror), wrapped by SQLA IntegrityError. I wonder if this is due to different databases raising very different kinds of errors. What DB were you using?

Comment: @IljaEverilä SQLite currently, though it will eventually be Postgresql. After I wrote the question I realized that it said it "wraps the DB-API IntegrityError", and thought, "Oh crap, did I just miss that?" Turned out I couldn't find any useful information *there* either.